# Do Juniper MX-series routers support per-interface jFlow/IPFIX sampling rate?

Tags: netflow, juniper-mx, ipfix

Do Juniper MX-series routers support per-interface jFlow/IPFIX sampling? For example, input sampling rate for xe-0/0/1 is one of 100 and input sampling rate for xe-0/0/2 interface is one of 500. I guess this is not supported.

Comment: As stated in [this example](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/example/sflow-configuring-mx-series.html), different sampling settings available for **sFlow** on MX platform starting from JunOS 18.1